# Elements of my view become unresponsive after returning to app after extended duration of time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my project, I have an issue. I have tried to replicate the bug but I can't seem to do it. However, it often occurs when I am using the app throughout the day. It seems the bug occurs when I return to the app after a significant duration of time after it has been dismissed but not terminated.

Elements of my Home view become unresponsive. I am not sure why this is the case, maybe it is my view hierarchy?

In the real version of the project, I am displaying steps via HealthKit and a native ad using Google Admob. Since I need to make the code I supply reproducible I have kept the structure of the view but removed aspects.

I have also removed the .onAppear method (this could have something to do with the bug?)

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Everywhere else in the app seems to work fine but I can't see anything I am doing differently.

Here is the view hierarchy and basic structure:

```
struct HomeTest: View {

 @State private var nativeAdViewConfig1 = NativeViewConfig(backgroundColor: Color.white, cornerRadius: 0, installColor: .blue)
        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                                
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    
                    // This HStack remains responsive
                    HStack {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                                                
                        Spacer()
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: ExampleView()) {
                            Text("Tap me")
                            
                        }
                      
                    }
                    .padding()
                   
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        
                        VStack {
                            // This becomes unresponsive
                                NavigationLink(destination: ExampleView()) {
                                    HStack(spacing: 12) {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                            
                                            Text("Nav Link")
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding(16)
                                    .background(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                    )
                                    .padding(.leading)
                                    .padding(.trailing)
                                }
                        }
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 16) {
                                
                                // This becomes unresponsive
                                Button(action: {
                                    print("Button Tapped")

                                })  {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("A button")
                                        
                                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                    }
                                    .padding(10)
                                    .background(.orange)
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                                }
                                                                
                                Divider()
                                    .frame(height: 50)
                                                           
                                // This becomes unresponsive
                                NavigationLink(destination: ExampleView()) {
                                    Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                                }
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                            .padding(.top, 35)
                        }
                        .offset(y: -25)
                        
                        VStack {
                            NativeAdView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Example view")
    }
}
```

In the actual project, I use a Native Ad. This could be interfering with the view. The Native ad is inside a ScrollView. Every button in this scroll view has the issue. The button outside the scroll view is fine. Here is the code for the native ad:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct NativeAdViewVCRepresentable : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var nativeViewConfig: NativeViewConfig

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let viewController = NativeViewController()
        viewController.nativeViewConfig = nativeViewConfig
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) { }
}


struct NativeViewConfig {

    var backgroundColor: Color? = .white
    var cornerRadius = 20.0
    var titleColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
    var subtitleColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
    var descriptionColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
    var priceColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
    var storeColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
    var installColor: Color? = Color("TileText")
}



struct NativeAdView: View {

    @Binding var nativeViewConfig: NativeViewConfig

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            NativeAdViewVCRepresentable(nativeViewConfig: $nativeViewConfig)
                .frame(height: 360, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(nativeViewConfig.cornerRadius)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class NativeViewController: UIViewController {

    var nativeViewConfig: NativeViewConfig?
    
    /// The height constraint applied to the ad view, where necessary.
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    /// The ad loader. You must keep a strong reference to the GADAdLoader during the ad loading
    /// process.
    var adLoader: GADAdLoader!

    /// The native ad view that is being presented.
    var nativeAdView: GADNativeAdView!

    /// The ad unit ID.
    let adUnitID = Constants.AdMob.nativeAdUnitId

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard
            let nibObjects = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NativeAdView", owner: nil, options: nil),
            let adView = nibObjects.first as? GADNativeAdView
        else {
            assert(false, "Could not load nib file for adView")
            return // Add this line to exit the scope
        }

        setAdView(adView)
        refreshAd()
    }


    func setAdView(_ view: GADNativeAdView) {

        nativeAdView = view
        self.view.addSubview(nativeAdView)
        nativeAdView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Layout constraints for positioning the native ad view to stretch the entire width and height
        // of the nativeAdPlaceholder.
        let viewDictionary = ["_nativeAdView": nativeAdView!]
        self.view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "H:|[_nativeAdView]|",
                options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
        )
        self.view.addConstraints(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "V:|[_nativeAdView]|",
                options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary)
        )
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    /// Refreshes the native ad.
    func refreshAd() {
        adLoader = GADAdLoader(
            adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: self,
            adTypes: [.native], options: nil)
        adLoader.delegate = self
        adLoader.load(GADRequest())
    }

    /// Returns a `UIImage` representing the number of stars from the given star rating; returns `nil`
    /// if the star rating is less than 3.5 stars.
    func imageOfStars(from starRating: NSDecimalNumber?) -> UIImage? {
        guard let rating = starRating?.doubleValue else {
            return nil
        }
        if rating >= 5 {
            return UIImage(named: "stars_5")
        } else if rating >= 4.5 {
            return UIImage(named: "stars_4_5")
        } else if rating >= 4 {
            return UIImage(named: "stars_4")
        } else if rating >= 3.5 {
            return UIImage(named: "stars_3_5")
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension NativeViewController: GADVideoControllerDelegate {

    func videoControllerDidEndVideoPlayback(_ videoController: GADVideoController) {
        print("Video playback has ended.")
    }
}

extension NativeViewController: GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate {

    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {

        // Set ourselves as the native ad delegate to be notified of native ad events.
        nativeAd.delegate = self

        // Deactivate the height constraint that was set when the previous video ad loaded.
        heightConstraint?.isActive = false

        nativeAdView.backgroundColor = UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.backgroundColor ?? .white)

        // Populate the native ad view with the native ad assets.
        // The headline and mediaContent are guaranteed to be present in every native ad.
        (nativeAdView.headlineView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.headline
        nativeAdView.mediaView?.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent

        // Some native ads will include a video asset, while others do not. Apps can use the
        // GADVideoController's hasVideoContent property to determine if one is present, and adjust their
        // UI accordingly.
        let mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        if mediaContent.hasVideoContent {
            // By acting as the delegate to the GADVideoController, this ViewController receives messages
            // about events in the video lifecycle.
            mediaContent.videoController.delegate = self
            print("Ad contains a video asset.")
        } else {
            print("Ad does not contain a video.")
        }

        // This app uses a fixed width for the GADMediaView and changes its height to match the aspect
        // ratio of the media it displays.
        if let mediaView = nativeAdView.mediaView, nativeAd.mediaContent.aspectRatio > 0 {
            heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: mediaView,
                attribute: .height,
                relatedBy: .equal,
                toItem: mediaView,
                attribute: .width,
                multiplier: CGFloat(1 / nativeAd.mediaContent.aspectRatio),
                constant: 0)
            heightConstraint?.isActive = true
        }

        // These assets are not guaranteed to be present. Check that they are before
        // showing or hiding them.
        (nativeAdView.bodyView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.body
        (nativeAdView.bodyView as? UILabel)?.textColor = UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.descriptionColor ?? .white)
        nativeAdView.bodyView?.isHidden = nativeAd.body == nil

        (nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?.setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: .normal)
        (nativeAdView.callToActionView as? UIButton)?.setTitleColor(UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.installColor ?? .white), for: .normal)
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isHidden = nativeAd.callToAction == nil

        (nativeAdView.iconView as? UIImageView)?.image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        nativeAdView.iconView?.isHidden = nativeAd.icon == nil

        (nativeAdView.starRatingView as? UIImageView)?.image = imageOfStars(from: nativeAd.starRating)
        nativeAdView.starRatingView?.isHidden = nativeAd.starRating == nil

        (nativeAdView.storeView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.store
        (nativeAdView.storeView as? UILabel)?.textColor = UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.storeColor ?? .white)
        nativeAdView.storeView?.isHidden = nativeAd.store == nil

        (nativeAdView.priceView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.price
        (nativeAdView.priceView as? UILabel)?.textColor = UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.priceColor ?? .white)
        nativeAdView.priceView?.isHidden = nativeAd.price == nil

        (nativeAdView.advertiserView as? UILabel)?.text = nativeAd.advertiser
        (nativeAdView.advertiserView as? UILabel)?.textColor = UIColor(nativeViewConfig?.subtitleColor ?? .white)
        nativeAdView.advertiserView?.isHidden = nativeAd.advertiser == nil

        // In order for the SDK to process touch events properly, user interaction should be disabled.
        nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        // Associate the native ad view with the native ad object. This is
        // required to make the ad clickable.
        // Note: this should always be done after populating the ad views.
        nativeAdView.nativeAd = nativeAd
    }

    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(adLoader) failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


extension NativeViewController: GADNativeAdDelegate {

    func nativeAdDidRecordClick(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdDidRecordImpression(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdWillPresentScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdWillDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdDidDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }

    func nativeAdIsMuted(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        print("\(#function) called")
    }
}
```

I have also noticed this caution:

[image]

Comment: So this example, run as is, also results in this issue?

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you do not display ad ?

Comment: @jnpdx I’m not sure as I’m not sure how to replicate the issue, I’m not sure if the error occurs here as it happens at what seems like random points

Comment: @PtitXav I can give that a try. It’s hard to test due to the random nature of the bug. Do you think this could be interfering?

Comment: I have seen apps becoming unresponsive after add display. Ad may use full screen and take control of inputs . If for some reason it does not give back control, your app may not receive any more inputs.

Comment: @PtitXav I think you're right. I have the Native Ad in a ScrollView{}. It's the buttons inside this ScrollView that become unresponsive. The button outside of the ScrollView is unaffected by the bug. Maybe it has something to do with my Ad view code. I edited the question to show it. Notice anything that could be causing this?

Comment: I saw : "nativeAdView.callToActionView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false" . May be this can explain your problem if you never reset it.